# Returning a substring in c# - exercism exercise question

Tags: c#

Very new to C#, hoping you can help! I am attempting [this question](https://exercism.org/tracks/csharp/exercises/log-levels) on Exercism.

From what I understand I need to return a substring of the methods argument which accepts a string.

So I call the method like below and it returns a substring which is equal to "Invalid operation".

```
LogLine.Message("[ERROR]: Invalid operation")
// => "Invalid operation"
```

My code:

```
static class LogLine
{
    public static string Message(string logLine)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Please implement the (static) LogLine.Message() method");
        
        // my attempt at an answer

        int first = logLine.IndexOf("[ERROR]:") + "[ERROR]:".length;
        int last = logLine.LastIndexOf("n");
        string str2 = logLine.Substring(first, last);
        return str2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this correctly, you basically want to ignore the first word in this case, which you can do by doing this:

```
public static string Message(string logLine)
{
    string firstWord = logLine.Split()[0];
    int charsToSkip = firstWord.Length + 1;
    return logLine[charsToSkip..];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any leading or trailing white space should be removed.For first task try this -

```html
public static string Message(string logLine) { var logs = logLine.Split(':'); return logs[1].Trim(); }
```